# Ubuntu 20.04 - AMD R9 270x Driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I'm using a Ubuntu Distro, based on Ubuntu 20.04. I'm currently searching to install my AMD R9 270x driver because I have a 1080p Display but the software doesn't let me change any resolution at all and I'm stuck with a 4:3 1024x768
Any idea where to find them? I searched on the AMD-Website and the only driver I could find for the R9 270x were for the Ubuntu version 16.x. Are there any recently driver? If not I could without any problem downgrade by Linux to the 16.x

Thanks for an Answer!!!

Comment: "Related" Ubuntu distros are off-topic at this site.

Comment: I could delete that I use it and it will change nothing

Comment: These are the latest drivers: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45
However, they won't work with the kernel version 5.8.0-40, which is in the latest Ubuntu 20.04 update. If you try installing them, it will fail half-way, and screw up your GPU drivers.